# Failed To Load Component, Checkout Page (Console Error)

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, javascript, magento2.3

I upgraded Magento from `2.2.1` to `2.3.2`, after that when i add any product to cart, on cart page i got these console errors:
[image]

and when i proceed to `Checkout` i get more error like these, also i can't see any option or fields like in below image:

**`Checkout Page`**
[image]
**`Console Errors`**
[image]

**`UPDATED IMAGE`**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can see, your content hasnt been deployed properly. The solution for this is to redeploy. please follow the below steps to do this

```
rm -rf var/view_processed/ pub/static/* generation/
bin/magento setup:di:compile 
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (if you have additional languages e.g. en_US en_GB de_DE) -f
bin/magento cache:flush
```

this should redeploy the static content and fix the issue if not i have seen a number of issues with the deployment process recently so you could try switching between production and development. you can do this by running

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

then run the commands above to redeploy content

Comment: I don't know what's actual issue, i disables all my custom modules, and the error gone also i saw that my `deploy:mode` is on `default` so i change it to production, now i'm getting 2 errors of `Failed to Load Component`  and `404`, should i update my question or raise another question. @DavaGordon

Comment: Switch to developer then switch to production once you have done that run setup:di:compile and setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: did as u said but getting the same error, i updated my question with an image please see above..... @DavaGordon

Comment: Basically its saying that file doesn't exist in static content so there can be 2 reasons for this. the first reason it is being removed in your theme or by a module. the second reason is the static content isn't being build correctly could be any number of reasons. lack of space / incorrect permissions.

Comment: Don't delete the .htaccess file inside the pub/static directory otherwise system will throw 404 error for files.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, in the last image of my question i got another error i just wanna share how i solved it, so the error was about `404 of jquery.hashchange.js`, but i found that in `Magento 2.3.2` there is no need for `jquery.hashchange.js`, in my project i have some Custome Module and overridden files which was messing with jquery, [This Commited Changes](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/6c46def154a3c43cc9a9f7518761e7ed09dc71a3) helped me, **Remove usage of $.browser as it's unused and deprecated in jQuery. Fixes**

Thank You.

Comment: The original issue raised was about static content the second issue is down to you using a poorly built theme which is incompatible with the new version of magento